# Pip on MINGW64?

Tags: python, pip, windows-10, mingw-w64

I was trying to install Jupyter via MSYS2 shell on a Windows 10 machine (as per https://jupyter.org/install, "Installing Jupyter with pip") - and the process crashed; then I found this:

[jupyter notebook fails to start · Issue #1540 · msys2/MSYS2-packages · GitHub](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/1540)

> You need to start jupyter notebook from the mingw64 shell, not from the msys2 shell.
>   For me a simple jupyter notebook works as expected.

Ok, so I wanted to try the MINGW64 shell.

Note, in the MSYS2 shell:

```
user@DESKTOP-PC MSYS /c/
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/e0/be401c003291b56efc55aeba6a80ab790d3d4cece2778288d65323009420/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 2.3MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.1
    Uninstalling pip-19.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-19.1
Successfully installed pip-19.1.1
```

So, pip works fine in MSYS2 shell. But if I try MINGW64:

```
user@DESKTOP-PC MINGW64 ~
$ python3 -m pip install jupyter
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/python3.exe: No module named pip

user@DESKTOP-PC MINGW64 ~
$ python2 -m pip install --upgrade pip
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/python2.exe: No module named pip
```

Note the paths of python above in MINGW64 shells; if we try to see what is the path of Python in MSYS2, it is different:

```
user@DESKTOP-PC MSYS /c/
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

user@DESKTOP-PC MSYS /c/
$ cygpath -w `which python3`
C:\msys64\usr\bin\python3.exe
```

Anyways - can I use `pip` for `python` in MINGW64 shell on Windows 10, and if so - how?

---

EDIT: Just tried installing pip with python3 in MINGW64 - does not work:

```
user@PC MINGW64 /c/Users/user/Desktop
$ python3 get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/e0/be401c003291b56efc55aeba6a80ab790d3d4cece2778288d65323009420/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
     |################################| 1.4MB 1.7MB/s
Collecting wheel
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/10/44230dd6bf3563b8f227dbf344c908d412ad2ff48066476672f3a72e174e/wheel-0.33.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4b0z8ro2\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 178, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4b0z8ro2\pip.zip\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 414, in run
    use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4b0z8ro2\pip.zip\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 58, in install_given_reqs
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4b0z8ro2\pip.zip\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 922, in install
    use_user_site=use_user_site, pycompile=pycompile,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4b0z8ro2\pip.zip\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 448, in move_wheel_files
    warn_script_location=warn_script_location,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4b0z8ro2\pip.zip\pip\_internal\wheel.py", line 544, in move_wheel_files
    generated.extend(maker.make(spec))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4b0z8ro2\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 405, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4b0z8ro2\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 309, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4b0z8ro2\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 245, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4b0z8ro2\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 384, in _get_launcher
    result = finder(distlib_package).find(name).bytes
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bytes'
```

Comment: That `mingw` interpreter being different path should also use different (its own) tree where it looks for its STL... and it seems to come without `pip` (some distros do). So, first step (should you want `pip`) is to install it: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: Thanks, @OndrejK. - I kinda thought that `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` would install pip if not present, but obviously, that cannot happen, since that command calls pip itself. Anyways, tried to install pip in MINGW64, cannot do it - updated the OP with the results ...

Comment: Sorry, I've been a bit swamped lately. I can see the failing code looking for `w32.exe` or `w64.exe` (depending on your system) launcher, but it's not immediately obvious to my why exactly does it fail (as those are packed in the wheel it downloaded). Unfortunately I also do not have a Windows system at hand to try to reproduce it and have a closer look. Perhaps try running the same through a debugger (`python3 -m pdb get-pip.py`) and poke around a bit to see what is the state when it fails?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With Mingw-64, pip is patched downstream in the package. To install the package run:
`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pip`

You should then be able to install jupyter and other packages using `python -m pip`, but avoid running `python -m pip --upgrade pip` because that will overwrite the packaged version.

I would also recommend using a virtualenv by running `python -m venv .venv` and `source .venv/bin/activate` to keep the pip installed packages completely separate.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it with pacman:

```
pacman -S python-pip
```

And if you need git:

```
pacman -S git
```

Comment: These are MSYS2 packages which run in a posix compatibility layer, this is not the same as the question which was for MINGW64.

Comment: The usefulness of this approach depends heavily on how (and which) Python was installed.